# Encrypting truststore password in WSO2 Api Manager 4.0.0 does not work

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, keystore, truststore

First of all I would like to state that I'm new to WSO2. I recently started a new job and I'm learning the platform at the moment.

My problem is this: The product is shipped with a default JKS keystore (wso2carbon.jks) and a truststore (client-truststore.jks). Also included is a script for encrypting different passwords you wan't to protect. The documentation of the platform doesn't specify all the steps you need to take, but I figured it out. Before running the script, the password for both the keystore and the trusstore works, as the server startup results in no error. But after encryption, i get this error when starting the server:

`ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ServerConnFactoryBuilder} - SECUREWEBHOOKSERVER Error opening Key store : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

If I choose not do encrypt the truststore password, I get no errors during startup.
In the file "deployment.toml" the password seems to be encrypted the same way as all of the other passwords.

I've found alot of documentation regarding keystore/truststore passwords and how to encrypt passwords in different WSO2 products. I can't find anyone with my problem though.

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now, searching, reading, trying and failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the truststore password. It doesn't need a password at all. There are no secrets in there.

Comment: In the documentation, they're using the truststore password in the example, so it should work though right? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/working-with-encrypted-passwords/